# Sublime minify a file automatically When i try to save it

Tags: php, ftp, sublimetext3, cpanel, filezilla

Sublime minify a file automatically When i try to save it. I have fetched this problem in many time. I am working with filezilla and Sublime text 3. it's look like this after reopen it (http://prntscr.com/ebxn87)

Comment: Welcome to SO  - Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding writing a good SO question.

Answer (score 1):

You have Minify plugin intalled, update this option

```
"auto_minify_on_save": true,
```

to

```
"auto_minify_on_save": false,
```

You can find it on : Preference->Packages Setting->Minify->Setting